# SharePoint 2013 Licensing - can I disable Standard features to not use CALs?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, licensing

I'm playing around with SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, and I have found two interesting buttons:

[image: SharePoint 2013 licensing buttons]

Some people told me, that if I deactivate those features I won't need CAL licences at all (same as Foundation, just have to pay for Enterprise Key), as those CALs are required for Standard and Enterprise features. I don't need any Standard feature, but I'm looking for official confirmation to correctly license my production environment before deployment. Can someone provide me a link to a licensing document where I can find official Microsoft position on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not true! If you have installed Standard or Enterprise you have installed Standard or Enterprise and you have to pay for Standard or Enterprise; Server license and CAL.

What you can do however is to limit the licenses on the CAL site using the `*-SPUserLicensing` cmdlets.

[Here's an example of usage and some notes about usage](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-a-look-at-the-new-options-for-managing-users-and-their-licensing)